# converting dd/mm/yyyy into yyyy/mm/dd using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

i'm quite new with php. i think this is quite straight forward but i'm confused.

i have a form which asks users for a date of their choice, the format they enter is dd/mm/yyyy

the linked mysql database is formatted yyyy/mm/dd, from what i understand you can't change this.

i'm just trying to figure out where i can change the format of the date. would it be in the sql line that sends the information?

i found this unrelated answer:

```
<?php 
$date = date("Y-m-d"); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO date_table VALUES ('$name', '$date')", $db_connection); 
?>
```

but i can't get this to work...

here are some snippets of the code i currently have:

```
// Check for night attending:
    if (empty($_POST['night_attending'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter the night you want to attend.';
    } else {
        $na = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['night_attending']));
    }
```

.....................................

```
// Make the query:
        $q = "INSERT INTO guests (first_name, last_name, email, night_attending) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln', '$e', '$na')";       
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.
        if ($r) { // If it ran OK.
```

.....................................

```
<p>Night Attending: <input type="text"id="datepicker"  name="night_attending" size="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['night_attending'])) echo $_POST['night_attending']; ?>" /></p>
```

thanks for your time guys.

alastair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### **Update:** (Based On Comments)

To get the date value from your form, you can do this:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['night_attending']));
```

Where it is assumed that:

- The data received is in valid format
- You are using `POST` method in your `<form>` tag or change accordingly.

---

You need to use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: @alsweet: Now that `$date` variable is created in the format you wanted, you can use it in your query. Let us know what is the problem still?

Comment: im not sure how to assign it the date from the form, ive tried $date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($na)); and then using $date in the post: $q = "INSERT INTO guests (first_name, last_name, email, night_attending) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln', '$e', '$date')";

Comment: awesome, works great.  thats what i thought, i did try that but i must have made some error within it. whats odd is its storing the month and day the other way round so it stores 02/11/2010 as 2010/02/11 using Y/m/d, but i changed it to Y/d/m which does the job. anyway thanks a lot for your help Sarfraz!

Comment: ah thanks, one last question :p, as its muddling up my days and months it doesn't work if i select a day after the 12th as it thinks these are months and simply enters the default date of 1970/01/01, i don't understand how it chooses which numbers from the form to be a day/month/year?    simply switching it to Y/d/m made it look right in the table but it still won't work after the 12th...

Comment: @alsweet: I am not sure about it but make sure that you validate the date and it comes in correct format when submitted. Also try putting this line before the code i posted: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`. Replace your time zone appropriately. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this code, to convert `dd/mm/yyyy` into `yyyy/mm/dd`:

```
$convert = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$converted = implode(/, array_reverse(explode(/, $convert)));
```

I know that there are some built-in functions to do it, but I think that by this way it's more customizable.